# Simplified forms of Maxwell's curl equations for special case of $\vec{J}$

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

From Maxwell's curl equations, obtain the particular differential equations for the case of
$\vec{J} = J_z(y,t)\hat{z}$.

The solution provided for this question shows something like this:

$\begin{vmatrix}
\vec{a_x}&\vec{a_y}&\vec{a_z}\\
0&\frac{\partial}{\partial y}&0\\
{E_x}&{E_y}&{E_z}\\
\end{vmatrix} = -\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$ and
$\begin{vmatrix}
\vec{a_x}&\vec{a_y}&\vec{a_z}\\
0&\frac{\partial}{\partial y}&0\\
{H_x}&{H_y}&{H_z}\\
\end{vmatrix} = \vec{J}+\frac{\partial \vec{D}}{\partial t}$

Why does the $\nabla$ have components with 0 value?

Answer (score 1):

$\nabla $  does not have zero components. I'm guessing that this is just a short-hand notation for the fact that derivatives of the fields w.r.t $x,z$ should vanish, as the sources have a translational symmetry along the $x,z$ coordinates. So of course $\partial_x \neq 0$, but $\partial_x E_x = \partial_x E_y = \partial_x E_z = 0$ etc.

Comment: Why does it have a symmetry along the $x$, $z$ coordinate? How do we define $\vec{E}$'s direction from the given $\vec{J}$?

Comment: The currents are independent of $x,z$, thus the problem has the translational syymetry, and thus the fields also have this symmetry, which means that they are independent of $x,z$. I did not say that we know something about the direction of $E$. Just the fact that the $x,z$ derivatives of any component vanish.